# How to get template page URL in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to get template page URL in WordPress and i create a function

```
function getTplPageURL($TEMPLATE_NAME){
  $url;
 //Code which i need

 $pages = query_posts(array(
     'post_type' =>'page',
     'meta_key'  =>'_wp_page_template',
     'meta_value'=> $TEMPLATE_NAME
 ));
 // cycle through $pages here and either grab the URL
 // from the results or do get_page_link($id) with 
 // the id of the page you want 
 $url = null;
 if(isset($pages[0])) {
     $url = get_page_link($pages[0]['ID']);
 }
 return $url;
}
```

but when i call this function this error has occurred

" Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_Post as array"

please help me

Answer (score 1):

Use the following standard WP function:

```
get_template_directory_uri()
```

Answer (score 1):

Why complicate things?

```
<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>
```

**Output:** http://your-wordpress-url.com/wp-content/themes/yourtheme

[**Reference**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `$pages[0]` is an object(`WP_Post`).

Try change `$pages[0]['ID']` to `$pages[0]->ID`.